# how to get the starting point and line number of Bad word form string in php

Tags: php

```
  $comment="Computer is Nice but the manufacturer **some bad word for him** i don;t lkie him)"
```

Now what i need to get the bad word's line and starting point(location of bad word) and then cut and insert bad sentence to database in badcomments table and good comment to good comment table I am confuse how to do it any php function can do it

Comment: i want to insert bad comment to diffenent table and good to different table

Comment: Could you also please explain what is the bad comments and what are the good comments?

Comment: Are there a prefix before the bad comments and good comments so we can filter it this way or are you looking for a script which are able to detect bad words and good words?

Comment: Like some abusing words is under bad words and good words in good word

Comment: Are you looking for a script that already has a list of abusing words and good words? or will you create that list yourself?

Comment: NO  there is no options for bad comment and good comment there is a comment box for comments i just want to filter good and bad comments in single comment box

Comment: i wiil create list my self i need an idea to filter data by  sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finding a word in a string from an array you can do it like this.

Here you can see if `$found`is true or false to see if it found a match and afterwards you can print the `$matches` out, so you can get the words that were bad.

`$badList = array("bad","reallybad");
 $testString = "there is a bad word in this comment reallybad"; 
 $found = preg_match_all("/\b(".implode($badList,"|").")\b/i",$testString,$matches);
 if($found){
    echo 'bad word found <br>';
    print_r($matches[1]);
 }
 else
    echo 'no bad words';`

if you would wan't to replace these bad words with something else, you can do it the following way.
`$badList = array("bad","reallybad");
 $testString = "there is a bad word in this comment reallybad";
 $replacement = '**BAD**';
 echo preg_replace("/\b(".implode($badList,"|").")\b/i",$replacement,$testString);`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is slightly ambiguous however...

Use strPos() to detect use of certain words or phrases.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Use str_replace to replace certain words or phrases.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

If you want to use a multiple search use an Array() as the needle for your haystack.

Once you done that do a simple query to insert your results into your tables.

Comment: I need to get replace word too and whole sentense